Why is AsyncOptions.DuplicateSignature property not working in System.enqueueJob function?
i have an issue with the class QueueableDuplicateSignature.
Precisely on the property DuplicateSignature of the AsyncOptions class
I'm trying to create a single Job for a certain process, call it "SendingEmail" that is triggered at the creation /edit of an sObject Record.
The result looked for is to avoid to create multiple Jobs at the same time, but instead to manage a batch of n records per Job before starting the logic of the following Job.
The code shown in the documentation seems to be a good starting point.
I gave the value "SendingEmail" at AsyncOption.DuplicateSignature parameter in the enqueueJob function:
AsyncOptions options = new AsyncOptions();
options.DuplicateSignature = QueueableDuplicateSignature.Builder().addString('SendingEmail').build();
System.enqueueJob(new MyQueueable(), options);

During the process the sObject record is edited and the logic correctly create subsequent Jobs starting one at the end of the other.
But Salesforce does not avoid creating multiple Jobs when an sObject record is separately created.
link of doc
I found little documentation regarding
QueueableDuplicateSignature.Builder()
Am i doing somehing incorrect or am i missing out on anything in the process?
Any help is appreciated

Without more information in your builder, you're going to be randomly blocking queueables from running properly. Consider adding more information, like a record Id, to try and block duplicates correctly.

thanks @sfdcfox there's a typo in code section, i'm editing it.
I add a String 'SendingEmail' that is the name of the queueable class.
I want that only one Job of this type is running at a time.
